# Como cargar lista desplegable en app.blade.php?? (laravel-vuejs)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

tengo una duda, necesito una lista desplegable en mi app.blade.php, ya lo tenia hecho con un componente de vue, pero se demora un poco en cargar, por lo que la descarte, ya que es necesario que sea rápida la carga para la selección. Así que es necesario que se muestre con php.

El tema es que el app.blade.php lo llamo en las vistas con @extends ya que tiene el head css etc...

Entonces he probado de varias formas:

1. {{ App\Http\Controllers\ComunidadController::showComunidades() }}
2. con un inject del controlador y llamar la función....
3. Y otras tonteras que no han funcionado.

y tengo dentro del app.blade.php

```
    <main>
    <div class="container">
     ACA DEBE IR
    <hr>
    <div>
    @yield('content')
   </main>
   @extends('layouts.footer')
 </div>
```

Y tengo el controlador:

```
 public function showComunidades(){
        $comunidades = //un get()
        return view('layouts/comunidades', compact('comunidades'));
    }
```

También lo tengo en una ruta, pero no se como llamarlo, lo unico que se me ocurre es aplicar php pero no creo que sea la solución.

view.php

```
Route::get('show_comunidades', 'ComunidadController@showComunidades');
```

Como podría llamar la vista del listado desplegable desde el app.blade?????
Alguna opinión???

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste pasar como argumento un json con tus "comunidades", y luego en la vista blade usas un foreach para mostrarlos en un select/acordeon o donde lo quieras mostrar?

Comment: Simplemente haces un foreach en tu vista como normalmente se hace, si quieres ver si los datos se pasaron a tu vista utiliza en tu vista {{ $comunidades }}

Comment: Es raro que con vuejs se tarde en cargar, son muchos datos? usas eloquent para traer los datos y mejorar el tiempo de respuesta?

Comment: @Lek es lo que pense, pero no creo que sea la mejor manera, pero es mi primera opción.
Creo que probare y le dare una vuelta con el axios....
Gracias por los comentarios, les comento.

Comment: @Dohko19 si lo pense, pero tendría que pasarle a todas las vistas este compact. La verdad tengo el servidor en cloud de google y es pequeño el component, la consulta es con laravel, y se demora poco, pero en celular se demora como 3 seg, y si lo agrego con php, se carga inmediato, por lo menos el <select>.
Gracias por el comentario, les comentare.